# how to loop through nested objects and push fields after comparing them in javascript/es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have the following 3 items from the structure of data below:

[image: how]

- Let's assume that `group` has three fields: `id`, `name`, `accountNumber` and because I have three items, two of them have the same `accountNumber`.

## What i want to do

I want to write a function with `javascript/es6` to loop through these objects, check the `id` and `accountNumber` in `group` and push that in a new array of objects named `results`.
(If any id contains the same `accountnumber` it should not be pushed to the new array below)

```
# new array 
# results = [
{
    id: 1,
    accountNumber: 2289,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    accountNumber: 9920,
  },
]
```

Because of my background with `python` i am struggling to accomplish this. any help would be very helpful.

Comment: I suggest using `map()` when you want to create a new array from an existing array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all other data object properties are irrelevant, and I correctly represented your data (the image is cropped):

```js
const data = [
  {group: {id: 1, name:"name1", accountNumber: 1234}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 2, name:"name2", accountNumber: 1235}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 3, name:"name3", accountNumber: 1234}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 4, name:"name4", accountNumber: 1236}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 5, name:"name5", accountNumber: 1237}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
]

const result = data.reduce((result, obj) => { 
    if(result.some(ele => ele.accountNumber === obj.group.accountNumber)) return result; 
    result.push({id: obj.group.id, accountNumber: obj.group.accountNumber});
    return result;
}, []);

//will filter out id 3 since it has same accountNumber as id 1
console.log(result)
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to help me it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This example should give you an idea about how to filter same account numbers

```js
data=[{id:2, name:"foo", accountNumber:20209393},{id:2, name:"bar", accountNumber:2020559393},{id:2, name:"foo", accountNumber:20209393}]

result=data.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  if(acc.length==0) {acc.push(curr)}
  else {
    acc.some(o => {
     if(o.accountNumber==curr.accountNumber){
      return acc
     }
     else acc.push(curr)
  })

}
  return acc
},[])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can actually achieve that a bit more concise by using a `Map`.

by design, a `Map` only has one value per key thus we can index by accountNumber which will be faster to check for reappearances.

Also, the `Map.set()` returns the whole Map, which comes in handy when used in `Array.reduce()` functions because we always have to return the accumulator within such.

The same could be achieved using a dictionary (`Object`) - see the second snippet - but a dictionary doesn't come as handy as a Map when used in `Array.reduce()` functions.

Using a Map:

```js
const data = [
  {group: {id: 1, name:"name1", accountNumber: 1234}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 2, name:"name2", accountNumber: 1235}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 3, name:"name3", accountNumber: 1234}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 4, name:"name4", accountNumber: 1236}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 5, name:"name5", accountNumber: 1237}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
]
const exists = (result, obj) => result.get(obj.group.accountNumber);
const result = data.reduce((result, obj) => !exists(result, obj) ? result.set(obj.group.accountNumber, {id: obj.group.id, accountNumber: obj.group.accountNumber}) : result, new Map())
console.log([...result.values()])
```

Using a dictionary:

```js
const data = [
  {group: {id: 1, name:"name1", accountNumber: 1234}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 2, name:"name2", accountNumber: 1235}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 3, name:"name3", accountNumber: 1234}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 4, name:"name4", accountNumber: 1236}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 5, name:"name5", accountNumber: 1237}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
]

const exists = (result, obj) => !!result[obj.group.accountNumber];
const result = data.reduce((result, obj) => {
  result[obj.group.accountNumber] = !exists(result, obj) ? {id: obj.group.id, accountNumber: obj.group.accountNumber} : result[obj.group.accountNumber];
  return result;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = [
   {group: {id: 1, name:"name1", accountNumber: 1234}},
   {group: {id: 2, name:"name2", accountNumber: 5678}},
   {group: {id: 3, name:"name3", accountNumber: 9101}},
   {group: {id: 4, name:"name4", accountNumber: 1213}},
   {group: {id: 5, name:"name5", accountNumber: 1415}},
]

const result = []

data.map(v => {
   const {id} = v.group;
   const {accountNumber} = v.group
   result.push({id, accountNumber})
})

console.log(result)
```

Or for a one-liner

```js
const data = [{
    group: {
      id: 1,
      name: "name1",
      accountNumber: 1234
    }
  },
  {
    group: {
      id: 2,
      name: "name2",
      accountNumber: 5678
    }
  },
  {
    group: {
      id: 3,
      name: "name3",
      accountNumber: 9101
    }
  },
  {
    group: {
      id: 4,
      name: "name4",
      accountNumber: 1213
    }
  },
  {
    group: {
      id: 5,
      name: "name5",
      accountNumber: 1415
    }
  },
]

const result = []

data.map(v => result.push({
  id: v.group.id,
  accountNumber: v.group.accountNumber
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also do without the whole pushing to an array part like this: return the result of a filter on the array. The filter will return only the elements for which the index is the first index of the element with the same account number:

```
const data = [
  {group: {id: 1, name:"name1", accountNumber: 1234}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 2, name:"name2", accountNumber: 1235}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 3, name:"name3", accountNumber: 1234}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 4, name:"name4", accountNumber: 1236}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
  {group: {id: 5, name:"name5", accountNumber: 1237}, plan:{}, plan_account:{}, plan_benefits:{}},
]

const result =
data.filter((element, index, array) => index == array.findIndex((elm)=>
element.group.accountNumber == elm.group.accountNumber));

console.log(result);
```